# Unique_copy not returning expected output

Tags: c++, c++11, unique

I have this simple code, i know i must be doing some silly mistake :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<string> coll{"one", "two", "two", "three", "four", "one"};
vector<string> col2(coll.size(), "");
unique_copy(coll.cbegin(), coll.cend(), col2.begin());
for(const auto& ele : col2)
    cout<<" - "<<ele;
cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Output -  `- one - two - three - four - one -`

I was expecting :-  `- one - two - three - four - -`

What am i missing?

EDIT: As pointed out in aswer - Damn, i was missing the definition of unique_copy itself.

Is there any function to do what i expectecd (delete unique elements irrespective of adjacency), other than inserting them in `ordered set` or sorting before unique copy as i want to keep the ordering.

Comment: As your original question is answered, I would suggest you create a new post for your follow-up question (unless there already exists one on SO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[std::unique_copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy) :

> Copies the elements from the range `[first, last)`, to another range beginning at `d_first` in such a way that there are no **consecutive** equal elements.

`one` is not consecutive in your case.

Try:

```
vector<string> coll{"one", "one", "two", "two", "three", "four"};
```

you will find the output as

```
- one - two - three - four -  -
```

Comment: yeah got it, "one" is not adjacent. Damn !!